# iOS 13+: Can't get a notification userInfo when opening a deeplink

Tags: ios, iphone, deep-linking, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

I have faced the problem that I can't solve with Notifications and Deeplinks.

When opening a deeplink UIApplication used to send a `UIApplication.didFinishLaunchingNotification` with `userInfo` that contained `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey` with the URL that was opened.

So we could subscribe to it like this:

```swift
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.didFinishLaunchingNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
    print(notification.userInfo) // prints UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey: url_that_opened_the_app
}
```

Now, after iOS 13 it does not happen: `userInfo` is `nil`.

**So the question is:** is there a way to receive a notification from Notification Center when app opens a deeplink?

*Thoughts: *
I think that it is caused by the fact that `UISceneDelegate` is in charge of opening deeplinks now, which is confirmed by the fact that if we remove the SceneDelegate, we can get our userInfo back.
I tried to find if any of SceneDelegate notifications provide us with such information, but they don't: both `didActivateNotification` and `willConnectNotification` give nothing.

Comment: Check my answer once..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can find the same with `SceneDelegate` as well.
Here is a [Sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19d3UWTk5GTKewziMNFrg9yVjOqzHa0Wr/view?usp=sharing) I made.

Once you launch your app from deep links, you will receive `connectionOptions` in

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
}
```

You can get your URL as follows:

```
if let context = connectionOptions.urlContexts.first as? UIOpenURLContext {
    print(context.url.absoluteString)
}
```

So your function will look like:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    
    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    
    if let context = connectionOptions.urlContexts.first {
        print(context.url.absoluteString)
        //Here you can pass this URL to your notification and perform your logic.
    }
}
```

DeepLink I tested was:
 **deeplinks://mycustomDeepLink**

Also I changed the scheme to `Wait for the Executable to Launch` to check the initial launch thing from deep links.
[image]

**Note:** Sometimes debugger doesn't work for whatsoever reason. So, in my sample, I added an alert view in the `ViewController`.

Comment: Hi Rajan! Thank you for your answer, but it is not what I've been searching for: I was wondering if we can receive a Notification (from Notification Center) with this data

Comment: @LeonidSilver You can rather fire your own notification by making a common structure of your data and posting the notification (irrespective of the presence of `SceneDelegate` or not), rather than relying on `UIApplication.didFinishLaunchingNotification` because these delegates only call when the app gets launched. So, you are indeed sure that your specific notification only fires when the app is launched and it has a deep link url

Comment: I am making an SDK that has no access to AppDelegate, so relying on Apple Notifications is the only option I see.